# PHP view special characters in a string

Tags: php, special-characters, var-dump

Trying to figure out, what `PHP` is doing with newlines and special characters. I have a string, when I do `var_dump($string)` the output is:

```
string 'ls -al

    free -m' (length=16)
```

How do I view the special characters buried in here? For example need to see if they are `\n` or`&#10` or whatever they are.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to see unprintable characters is by printing `bin2hex($string)`. This gives you an actual binary dump of the string. Compare this with your favorite [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) or other table specific to the encoding your string is in.

Comment: Ok, so the output of the hex is `6c73202d616c0d0a66726565202d6d` which using a converter from hex to ascii outputs `ls -al??free -m` notice the ??. Those should be \n. Any idea what the heck is going on?

Comment: The hex dump looks pretty normal. The `0d0a` in the middle is simply a CRLF Windows linefeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're running your command in an unix environnement with PHP Cli, you may try using [cat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat).

```
php file.php | cat -e
```

Else, you can handle var_dump into a string and display manually special chars :

```
$string = "test
test";

$dump = var_export($string, true);
for ($i = 0; ($i < strlen($dump)); $i++) {
    if ((ord($dump[$i]) < 32) || (ord($dump[$i]) > 127)) {
        echo '(' . ord($dump[$i]) . ')';
    } else {
        echo $dump[$i];
    }
}

// will output 'test(13)(10)test' on Windows, 'test(10)test' on Unix systems.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
preg_match("/(&#[0-9]+;)|[\t\r\n]/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```